# Testing hypotheses about parameters using posterior distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian

My doubt's the following: I have a parameter $\theta$ and I am seeking to evaluate the hypothesis that $\theta > c$, where $c \in (0, 1)$ using Bayesian methods.

The parameter has a known prior $\pi (\theta)$ which follows a Beta distribution $\mathcal{B} (\alpha_s , \beta_s)$, furthermore, some data $X$ is gathered and it has density $f(X \mid \theta)$, which also follows a Beta distribution $\mathcal{B} (\alpha_f , \beta_f)$. The posterior distribution of $\theta$ can thus be found using Bayes' Rule for continuous priors and likelihoods.

I am relatively new to Bayesian methods and come from a frequentist background, so my reasoning would tell me that the likelihood that $\theta > c$ given the posterior $\pi (\theta \mid X)$ is given by the survival function of $c$ given the distribution, i.e. $s(c \mid \pi (\theta \mid X))$. I would essentially be computing the $p$-value of $c$ in the posterior distribution, and I know most Bayesian statisticians hate using $p$-values. I've looked into Bayes factors but I have seen them being brought up only in the context of model selection.

What would be a more Bayesian way to evaluate this hypothesis, or is my reasoning acceptable?

Comment: Does the distribution of $X$ somehow depend on $\theta$? If not, what are we talking about? And if so, how?

Comment: Using the same symbol, $\pi,$ to refer to various different functions is obnoxious and incorrect and impairs understanding. Unfortunately it is widespread.

Comment: One could write $\pi_X(x),$ with a capital $X$ denoting the random variable and lower-case $x$ denoting the argument to the density function.

Comment: Without any information about the way in which the distribution of $X$ depends on $\theta,$ this cannot be answered.

Comment: Assuming that you had the posterior distribution characterized in some way (either in a closed form or some samples from it), then you would just look at the probability that the parameter is greater than $c$. That is $P[\theta > c | X]$, which is not the likelihood that $\theta > c$, but the posterior probability that the parameter is greater than $c$. If you had a density for the posterior this would just be the mass that the posterior assigns to the region of values greater than $c$, if you have samples then it would be approximated by the number of samples greater than $c$.